# iOS switch statement won't work

Tags: ios, switch-statement

I'm having trouble with an iOS app I'm developing: I used a switch statement in two of the screens to handle multiple replies to questions but they don't seem to work correctly: maybe I committed some mistake building them but since I'm still learning iOS I'm not sure of what it is.

Here is the code for these screens:

**Riddle.m**

```
#import "Riddle.h"

@interface Riddle()

@end

@implementation Riddle

int reply;

-(void) viewDidLoad
{

    _etiqueta = @" 1: Que es allò blanc que tenia Santiago?";
    self.label.text = self.etiqueta;

    _eti = @"";
    self.lab.text = self.eti;

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
            action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}

-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [_resposta resignFirstResponder];
}

-(IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender
{
    switch (reply)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            _resposta.text = @"cavall";
            _eti = @"Correcte!";
            _resposta.text = @"";
            self.lab.text = self.eti;
            _etiqueta = @" 2: Què portes als peus?";
            self.label.text = self.etiqueta;
            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            _resposta.text = @"sabates";
            _eti = @"Correcte!";
            _resposta.text = @"";
            self.lab.text = self.eti;
            _etiqueta = @" 3: Què tires en l'oca?";
            break;
        }

        case 3:
        {
            _resposta.text = @"daus";
            _eti = @"Correcte!";
            _resposta.text = @"";
            self.lab.text = self.eti;
            _etiqueta = @" 4: Amb què ve l'hamburguesa?";
            break;
        }

        case 4:
        {
            _resposta.text = @"patates";
            _eti = @"Correcte!";
            _resposta.text = @"";
            self.lab.text = self.eti;
            _etiqueta = @" 5: Què té el pegàs?";
            self.label.text = self.etiqueta;
            break;
        }

        case 5:
        {
            _resposta.text = @"ales";
            _eti = @"Correcte! Les has encertades totes!";
            self.lab.text = self.eti;
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            _eti = @"Incorrecte!";
            _resposta.text = @"";
            self.lab.text = self.eti;
            break;
        }

    }

}

@end
```

**Riddle.h**

```
@interface Riddle : UIViewController

@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel * label;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UITextField * resposta;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIButton * enviar;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel * lab;


@property (strong, atomic) NSString * etiqueta;
@property (strong, atomic) NSString * eti;



@end
```

**Colors.m**

```
#import "Colors.h"

@interface Colors()
@end

@implementation Colors


-(void) viewdidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 240, 300, 30)];
    [self.view addSubview: label];
    label.text = @"Introdueix el color que vols que es mostri.";
    label.numberOfLines = 4;
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [_color resignFirstResponder];
}

int colored;

-(IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender
{

    switch(colored)
    {
        case 1:{
            _color.text = @"vermell";
            _color.text=@"";
            _correcte=@"Color vàlid";
            self.correct.text = self.correcte;
            UIView *un = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
            self.un.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.jpg"]];
            break;
        }

        case 2:{
            _color.text = @"blau";
            _color.text=@"";
            _correcte=@"Color vàlid";
            self.correct.text = self.correcte;
            UIView *dos = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
            self.dos.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.jpg"]];
            break;
        }

        case 3:{
            _color.text = @"groc";
            _color.text=@"";
            _correcte=@"Color vàlid";
            self.correct.text = self.correcte;
            UIView *tres = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
            self.tres.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow.jpg"]];
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            _color.text = @"marro";
            _color.text=@"";
            _correcte=@"Color vàlid";
            self.correct.text = self.correcte;
            UIView *quatre = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
            self.quatre.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"brown.jpg"]];
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            _color.text = @"rosa";
            _color.text=@"";
            _correcte=@"Color vàlid";
            self.correct.text = self.correcte;
            UIView *cinc = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
            self.cinc.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"pink.jpg"]];
            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            _color.text = @"taronja";
            _color.text=@"";
            _correcte=@"Color vàlid";
            self.correct.text = self.correcte;
            UIView *sis = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
            self.sis.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"orange.jpg"]];
            break;
        }
        case 7:
        {
            _color.text = @"negre";
            _color.text=@"";
            _correcte=@"Color vàlid";
            self.correct.text = self.correcte;
            UIView *set = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
            self.set.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"black.jpg"]];
            break;
        }
        case 8:
        {
            _color.text =@"verd";
            _color.text=@"";
            _correcte=@"Color vàlid";
            self.correct.text = self.correcte;
            UIView *vuit = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
            self.vuit.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.jpg"]];
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            _color.text = @"blanc";
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alerta!"
                                        message:@"Color no vàlid!"
                                       delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel·lar"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil
              ] show];
            _color.text=@"";
            break;
        }
    }

}

@end
```

**Colors.h**

```
@interface Colors : UIViewController

@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel * label;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UITextField * color;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIButton * enviar;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel * correct;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * correcte;

@property (weak) IBOutlet UIView * un;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIView * dos;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIView * tres;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIView * quatre;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIView * cinc;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIView * sis;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIView * set;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIView * vuit;


@end
```

I'd be very grateful if you could help me fix these.

Comment: What is the error? Have you verified that the value of `reply` is valid and which case statement is executed? It is mysterious what `reply` is. Best to use the ivar accessors instead of direct access.

Comment: You should try to avoid global variables.

Comment: As suggested above, you show a bunch of code but you don't show how the value of `reply` is set/changed.

Comment: Since switches only work with int values I thought I could make it work by allocating each reply to a case but... Maybe I need to think it over.

Comment: I don't think that is your problem, use the debugger and breakpoints to see what is actually happening. `NSLog()` can also help. You still have not described what is happening that is incorrect.

Comment: In the "colors" screen, even if I insert a correct color, the Alert message always pops out. And in "riddle" it jumps into the debug panel, meaning it crashes.

Comment: The question still stands: where do you set values for `reply` or `colored`?  You define them and test them but I don't see how they're modified.